# Yelp search Api in iOS

Tags: ios, yelp

I am working on a app in which I have to show  accessories, their price & other information from Yelp.
After a lot of searching I have found a useful link: https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/tree/master/v2/ios
But this method is not working for me.

Until now I have only used a single web service which is working & other's giving error like missing parameter.

This is working:

```
http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=mobile&ywsid=PyHVqegFdleV******&tl_lat=37.9&tl_long=-122.5&br_lat=37.788022&br_long=-122.399797
```

Is there another API call which returns me the price , offers & other information because above one is for review.

Comment: I have edited as much I understood still you need to edit it's link ,I think link are not proper. For e.g. http://api.yelp.com/business_review_search?term=mobile&ywsid=PyHVqegFdleV**&tl_lat=37.9&tl_long=-122.5&br_lat=37.788022&br_long=-122.399797 (this is working fine)
Also do provide code for much more understand.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer: [How to search local business by name, location in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601838/how-to-search-local-business-by-name-location-in-ios/26605560#26605560)

In success Venue block information about event

```
-(instancetype)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict {

self = [super init];

if (self) {

    self.name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.venueId = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
    self.thumbURL = [dict objectForKey:@"image_url"];
    self.ratingURL = [dict objectForKey:@"rating_img_url"];
    self.yelpURL = [dict objectForKey:@"url"];
    self.venueId = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
    self.reviewsCount =[[dict objectForKey:@"review_count"] stringValue];
    self.categories = [dict objectForKey:@"categories"][0][0];
    self.distance = [dict objectForKey:@"distance"];
    self.price = [dict objectForKey:@"deals.options.formatted_price"];
    self.address = [[[dict objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"address"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
    NSArray *adr = [[dict objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"display_address"];
    self.displayAddress = [adr componentsJoinedByString:@","];
}
return self;
```

}