# How to search local business by name, location in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios7, google-places-api, yelp

I am working on project in which we are displaying local business search. I am using YELP to search local business. As per [YELP Documentation](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api) i have created query. But it gives result based on location only.

I am trying with Google Place API but not getting desired result.

My YELP request - http://api.yelp.com/v2/search/?term=restaurant&location=nyc&limit=20&offset=1
My Google Place API request - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=hotels+in+nyc&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyCHwd5OgRXdeuTWV46SHdMLq2lXL20t22U

1. How can i get result by business name & location as well using any YELP or Google Place API?
2. Which one is better to use YELP or Google Place API?

Comment: What is wrong with the google place api? It is giving response no?

Comment: Yes, it is giving response but gives list of all restaurant in NYC.
I want to search specific restaurant "XYZ" in NYC. Also i am not able to get restuarant icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem using [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) -

Thanks to [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16043627/ios-hotel-cafe-restaurant-search/16043858#16043858).

We get JSON/XML response

1. Search hotels near City:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=hotels+in+Pune&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

2. Search specific place in city:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=[SearchPlaceName]+in+[CityName]&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

3. Search specific place in city by given type:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=[SearchPlaceName]+in+[CityName]&type=[PlaceType]&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

- To retrieve image/icons for restaurant/place -

As per [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/photos).

We can use `photo_reference` & request like -

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=CoQBegAAAFg5U0y-iQEtUVMfqw4KpXYe60QwJC-wl59NZlcaxSQZNgAhGrjmUKD2NkXatfQF1QRap-PQCx3kMfsKQCcxtkZqQ&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere
```

Answer (score 0):

1) I used Yelp API. Url for special business - http://api.yelp.com/v2/business/
For global search - http://api.yelp.com/v2/search
After search you must correctly pass data in api search url. Notice of url signature in **NSStringWithFormat**. And don't forget OAuth keys! My request:

```
-(void)searchBy:(NSString *)categoryFilter inLocationCity:(NSString *)aLocationCity {

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?term=%@&location=%@",
                       YELP_SEARCH_URL,
                       categoryFilter,
                       aLocationCity];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY
                                                secret:OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET];

OAToken *token = [[OAToken alloc] initWithKey:OAUTH_TOKEN
                                       secret:OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET];

id<OASignatureProviding, NSObject> provider = [[OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider alloc] init];
NSString *realm = nil;

OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL
                                                               consumer:consumer
                                                                  token:token
                                                                  realm:realm
                                                      signatureProvider:provider];

[request prepare];

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (conn) {
    self.urlRespondData = [NSMutableData data];
}
```

}

Also add methods NSURLConnectionDelegate:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

[self.urlRespondData setLength:0];
```

}

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d {
[self.urlRespondData appendData:d];
```

}

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

NSError *e = nil;
NSDictionary *resultResponseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.urlRespondData
                                                                   options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                     error:&e];
if (self.resultArray && [self.resultArray count] > 0){

    [self.resultArray removeAllObjects];
}

if (!self.resultArray) {
    self.resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
DLog(@"YELP response %@", resultResponseDict);

if (resultResponseDict && [resultResponseDict count] > 0) {

    if ([resultResponseDict objectForKey:@"businesses"] &&
        [[resultResponseDict objectForKey:@"businesses"] count] > 0) {

        for (NSDictionary *venueDict in [resultResponseDict objectForKey:@"businesses"]) {

            Venue *venueObj = [[Venue alloc] initWithDict:venueDict];
            [self.resultArray addObject:venueObj];
        }
    }
}

[self.delegate loadResultWithDataArray:self.resultArray];
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this is the same case `searchBy:inLocationCity:` will search restaurant at 'xyz' location. but i want to search 'abc' restaurant at 'xyz' location. 
How can i get result like this?

Comment: set special coordinates, and special restaurant.id, Yelp output event by id

Comment: ok. i will try with coordinates. but if its possible can you tell the `parameter name` for `restaurant.id`?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(instancetype)initWithDict:(NSDictionary *)dict {

self = [super init];

if (self) {

    self.name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.venueId = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
    self.thumbURL = [dict objectForKey:@"image_url"];
    self.ratingURL = [dict objectForKey:@"rating_img_url"];
    self.yelpURL = [dict objectForKey:@"url"];
    self.venueId = [dict objectForKey:@"id"];
    self.reviewsCount =[[dict objectForKey:@"review_count"] stringValue];
    self.categories = [dict objectForKey:@"categories"][0][0];
    self.distance = [dict objectForKey:@"distance"];
    self.price = [dict objectForKey:@"deals.options.formatted_price"];
    self.address = [[[dict objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"address"] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
    NSArray *adr = [[dict objectForKey:@"location"] objectForKey:@"display_address"];
    self.displayAddress = [adr componentsJoinedByString:@","];
}
return self;
```

}

Method with yelp response values...You need just id. Coordinates need for you location...When you get some venues see theirs id with Log or print.